# How to use getColumnMeta?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently I use MySQLi and I try to convert all my MySQLi to PDO.

In MySQLi I have this code and it work very fine:

```
// connection string in MySQLi

if ($query = $connection->prepare("SELECT u.ID as ID,
                          u.Username as Username,
                          u.Firstname as Firstname,
                          u.Lastname as Lastname,
                          // ... many more
                     FROM Users u
               INNER JOIN Gender g ON u.Gender = g.id
                          // ... many more
                    WHERE u.ID = ?")) {

$query->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['ID']);
$query->execute();
$metaResults = $query->result_metadata();
$fields = $metaResults->fetch_fields();
$statementParams = '';

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (empty($statementParams)) {
        $statementParams.="\$column['" . $field->name . "']";
    } else {
        $statementParams.=", \$column['" . $field->name . "']";
    }
}

$statment = "\$query->bind_result($statementParams);";

eval($statment);
$query->store_result();

$affected = $query->num_rows;
// this request return me only ONE row

if ($affected == 1) {
    while ($query->fetch()) {
        foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == "lookingFor") {
                $row_tmb[$key] = formatLookingFor($value, $language, "");
            } else {
                $row_tmb[$key] = utf8_encode($value);
                $row_tmb[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $results[] = $row_tmb;
    }

    $query->free_result();
    $query->close();

    $profileData = $results[0];
    // ... other code    
}
```

This is return to my all column names and all 1 data row and I'm verry happy. So, I try to convert this code into PDO with new PDO code:

```
// good connection string without error in PDO code and the same query as you see up.
if ($query = $connection->prepare($sql)) {
    $query->execute();
    $metaResultsColNumber = $query->columnCount();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metaResultsColNumber; $i++) {
        $metaResults[] = $query->getColumnMeta($i, ['name']);
    }
    var_dump($metaResults);

    $fields = $metaResults->fetchColumn();
    var_dump($fields);
    $statementParams = '';

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (empty($statementParams)) {
            $statementParams.="\$column['" . $field->name . "']";
        } else {
            $statementParams.=", \$column['" . $field->name . "']";
        }
    }
    $statment = "\$query->bind_result($statementParams);";

    eval($statment);
    $query->store_result();

    $affected = $query->num_rows;

    // TRACE
    printf("SQL %d row(s) return", $affected);

    if ($affected == 1) {
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == "lookingFor") {
                    $row_tmb[$key] = formatLookingFor($value, $language, "");
                } else {
                    $row_tmb[$key] = utf8_encode($value);
                }
            }

            $results[] = $row_tmb;
        }

        $query->free_result();
        $query->close();

        $profileData = $results[0];
```

And I can't obtain 1) the right column names 2) the data of the returning row

I try to read help into this site and PHP MySQL PDO documentation from many hours.

Comment: `getColumnMeta` only takes one argument, what is the second argument for? I think you meant `->getColumnMeta($i)['name']`. I have no idea what you're trying to do with `$fields = $metaResults->fetchColumn()`. `$metaResults` is an array, no a PDO object.

Comment: PDO doesn't have a `store_result()` method, why are you calling that?

Comment: `$query->num_rows` should be `$query->rowCount()`. It seems like you're hardly making any attempt to replace mysqli functions with the PDO equivalents.

Comment: Where do you set `$column`? Should it be `while ($column = $query->fetch())`?

Comment: It looks like you have that same problem in the original mysqli code. How did that ever work?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code, I don't really have the time to find them all and write a good answer. Sorry. I think you need to make sure you have error reporting enabled, so you can see all the errors you're getting by using wrong function names and uninitialized variables.

Comment: if after the foreach($fields as $filed) is not correct PDO code is because the previous code is not working at the moment i correct this code after first step

Comment: My MySQLi code is working i don't write all the code before and after the result is a good json string

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like that?

```
//Datastrucure 
include("pdo_dbconnect.php");
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = "' . $_SESSION[$fenster .'_tabelle'] . '" and table_schema = "' .$database.'"');
$stmt->execute();

$f = -1;
while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $f += 1;
    //pmsg($data['COLUMN_NAME'] . ' ' .$data['DATA_TYPE'] . ' ' . $data['CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH']);
    $_SESSION['_fieldName'][$f] = $data['COLUMN_NAME'];
    $_SESSION['_fieldLenght'][$f] = $data['CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH'];
    $_SESSION['_extra'][$f] = $data['EXTRA'];
}
```

Comment: I need in just ONE query obtain the list of name of column and the data from the row returned

Comment: I had the same problem 6 months ago. But PDO does not support that. I had to do 2 queries.